# Swing and unicode character

Tags: java, swing

I am having problem typing character glottal stop into a JTable, 
and only 0241 and 0242 (hex: latin capital letter glottal stop, latin small letter glottal stop)  those which were added in unicode version 5.0. 
Using Windows XP, I can type these characters in Firefox, but not in JTable, or Notepad (where I tried to use same fonts as firefox should be using).

It works in linux though.

Comment: Do you know if the font that your app is usings contains full charset that you need?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know either font nor charset where this glottal stop is used. Or in other words I don't know how to find answer to your question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows XP seems to not support [Unicode 5.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drintl/archive/2005/06/01/unicodequestion.aspx). Also, it depends on the installation, try installing support for asian languages, this adds fonts and other stuff.

Comment: I couldn't verify it (asked for someone else). But will accept it as more probable explanation.